# Access service on subdomain in Kubernetes

Tags: domain-name-system, docker, openstack, coreos, kubernetes

I have following setup:

- **Private OpenStack Cloud** - o̲n̲l̲y̲ Web UI (Horizon) is accessible

  (API is restricted but maybe I could get access)
- I have used **CoreOS** with a setup of one *master* and *three nodes*
- Resources are standardized (as default of OpenStack)
- I followed the getting-started guide for CoreOS (i.e. I'm using the default YAMLs for cloud-config provided) on [GitHub](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/docs/getting-started-guides)

As I read extensions such like Web UI (kube-ui) can be added as Add-On - which I have added (only kube-ui).

Now if I run a test such like simple-nginx I get following output:

creating pods:

```
$ kubectl run my-nginx --image=nginx --replicas=2 --port=80
```

creating service:

```
$ kubectl expose rc my-nginx --port=80 --type=LoadBalancer          
NAME       LABELS         SELECTOR       IP(S)     PORT(S)
my-nginx   run=my-nginx   run=my-nginx             80/TCP
```

get service info:

```
$ kubectl describe service my-nginx                                                                                                
Name:           my-nginx
Namespace:      default
Labels:         run=my-nginx
Selector:       run=my-nginx
Type:           LoadBalancer
IP:             10.100.161.90
Port:           <unnamed>   80/TCP
NodePort:       <unnamed>   31170/TCP
Endpoints:      10.244.19.2:80,10.244.44.3:80
Session Affinity:   None
No events.
```

*I can access my service from every(!) external IP of the nodes.*

My question now is as follows:

*How can access any started service ether with a subdomain and therefore how can I set this configuration (for example I have domain.com as example) or could it be printed out on which node-IP I have to access my service (although I have only two replicas(?!))?*

To describe my thoughts more understandable I mean following:

- given domain: **domain.com** (pointing to master)
- start service **simple-nginx**
- service can be accessed with **simple-nginx.domain.com**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer to all these people that see it after 5 years since the question got asked.

Tech got better and now we have [ingress in k8s](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) :D.

To make use of subdomains, deploy ingress controller e.g. [nginx ingress controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/)

and create an ingress object:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "simple-nginx.domain.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: simple-nginx
            port:
              number: 80
```

Now all that is left to do, is to create a dns record for `*.domain.com` and point it to the ingress IP seen in ADDRESS column.

```
$ kubectl get ingress
NAME          CLASS    HOSTS                      ADDRESS           PORTS   AGE
ingress       <none>   simple-nginx.domain.com    xxx.yyy.zzz.kkk   80      2d20h
```

Comment: and its solved!

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things:

- Run the kube-proxy on all nodes you want to access the VIPs (virtual IPs) for the services
- Point the node's DNS in /etc/resolv.conf to point to the DNS server that is running in the kubernetes cluster.